# IOS camera stopped working

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

For some reason I am getting a null image back in my IOS application whether I take a photo or grap a photo from the gallery.  It was working and returning photos to my view controller and then all of a sudden it stopped working even though I did not make any changes to the program.  Is this caused by a memory problem?  If I take a photo through the program, it does put the photo out to the gallery but does not return it to the view controller.  Any ideas on what the problem might be?   Below is my get photo logic:

```
- (IBAction)getPhoto:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and below is my return logic after the photo was selected and returns a null image:

```
  - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {

   UIImage *image =  (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
            UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

self.photoImage.image = image;
self.uploadImage = image;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: Is this happening even after you restart your application or not?

Comment: I rerun the application on my Iphone if that is what you mean about restarting the application. It continues to happen every time I run it. Should I delete the application from my phone and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the flase alarm but I noticed that my image went way in my xib file.  Once I restored that it worked.  I don't understand why IOS doesn't detect a missing image when trying to update it.